# When commit_fee (fee_per_kw) renegotiation?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, fee-estimation

Looking at my channels on lnd node, `fee_per_kw` values are different for some channels (13332 or 6422).

1. How is the `fee_per_kw` calculated when opening the channel? Does it take current bitcoin fees estimation at some threshold?
2. When should it recalculate (is it automatic?)
3. Is there a manual way of setting the custom `fee_per_kw` parameter?
4. Is there a manual way of triggering recalculation?

(I'd love some read materials on this topic as well if available).